# Create a new table by combining (appending) data from two existing Excel tables for three common columns

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a table in a new worksheet (same workbook) by combining (appending) data from two existing Excel tables for three common columns in the two tables.

I got the error

> object variable or with block variable not set"

on the Copy headers to new table line.

```vb
Sub CombineTablesToNewWorksheet()
    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim table1 As ListObject, table2 As ListObject, newTable As ListObject
    Dim commonColumns As Variant
    Dim lastRowTable1 As Long, lastRowTable2 As Long, newRow As Long
    
    ' Set the tables
    Set table1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1") ' Replace "Sheet1" and "Table1" with your sheet and table names
    Set table2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2") ' Replace "Sheet2" and "Table2" with your sheet and table names
    
    ' Set common column names
    commonColumns = Array("Column1", "Column2", "Column3") ' Replace with your common column names
    
    ' Create a new worksheet
    Set wsNew = Sheets.Add
    
    ' Set the new table in the new worksheet
    Set newTable = wsNew.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1").Resize(1, UBound(commonColumns) + 1), , xlYes)
    
    ' Copy headers to new table
    For i = LBound(commonColumns) To UBound(commonColumns)
        newTable.ListColumns(i + 1).DataBodyRange.Value = commonColumns(i)
    Next i
    
    ' Find the last row of each table
    lastRowTable1 = table1.ListRows.Count
    lastRowTable2 = table2.ListRows.Count
    
    ' Combine rows based on common columns from Table1
    For i = 1 To lastRowTable1
        newRow = newTable.ListRows.Count + 1
        newTable.ListRows.Add
        For Each colName In commonColumns
            newTable.ListColumns(colName).DataBodyRange(newRow, 1).Value = table1.ListColumns(colName).DataBodyRange(i, 1).Value
        Next colName
    Next i
    
    ' Combine rows based on common columns from Table2
    For i = 1 To lastRowTable2
        newRow = newTable.ListRows.Count + 1
        newTable.ListRows.Add
        For Each colName In commonColumns
            newTable.ListColumns(colName).DataBodyRange(newRow, 1).Value = table2.ListColumns(colName).DataBodyRange(i, 1).Value
        Next colName
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `newTable.HeaderRowRange = commonColumns`

Comment: Did any of these answers work for you? If so please toggle checkmark next to that answer to mark issue solved

Answer (score 0):

A ListColumn's `DataBodyRange` is where the data goes, not where the actual header is. You should be using something like

`newTable.ListColumns(i + 1).Name = commonColumns(i)`

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just bring both tables into PowerQuery using **data ... from table/range**, then create a 3rd query to combine them using **data ... get data .. combine queries ... append...**.  Simple, no need to home code

Answer (score 0):

Create the new table with enough rows for both tables combined and copy the values as ranges.

```vb
Sub CombineTablesToNewWorksheet1()

    Dim wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim table1 As ListObject, table2 As ListObject, newTable As ListObject
    Dim cols As Long, n1 As Long, n2 As Long
    Dim commonColumns, c as Long, sCol As String
    
    ' Set common column names
    commonColumns = Array("Column1", "Column2", "Column3") ' Replace with your common column names
    
    ' Set the tables
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set table1 = .Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1") ' Replace "Sheet1" and "Table1" with your sheet and table names
        Set table2 = .Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table2") ' Replace "Sheet2" and "Table2" with your sheet and table names
        ' Create a new worksheet
        Set wsNew = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    End With
    
    cols = UBound(commonColumns) + 1
    n1 = table1.ListRows.Count
    n2 = table2.ListRows.Count
   
    ' Set the new table in the new worksheet
    Set newTable = wsNew.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1").Resize(n1 + n2, cols), , xlYes)
    With newTable
        ' Copy headers to new table
        .HeaderRowRange = commonColumns
        'Copy Data
        For c = 1 To cols
            sCol = commonColumns(c - 1)
            .DataBodyRange(1, c).Resize(n1, 1) = table1.ListColumns(sCol).DataBodyRange.Value
            .DataBodyRange(n1 + 1, c).Resize(n2, 1) = table2.ListColumns(sCol).DataBodyRange.Value
        Next
    End With
    
End Sub
```